# Mostrar valores formulario

Tags: jquery

Buenas,

Tengo un formulario y me gustaría obtener los valores escritos en él, e insertarlos posteriormente en una tabla. Yo lo que he hecho es obtener el valor del campo mediante `.val()` y eso lo inserto, pero haciéndolo así en vez de aparecer mi resultado, aparece la palabra *undefined*. ¿Cual es el error que cometo?

Gracias y salud!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var contadorObjetivo = 0; //Contador para añadir objetivo con sus respectivos ejercicios.
  var contadorEjercicio = 0; //Contador para añadir ejercicios.

  // JS para crear rutinas estilo POWER

  $('#Anyadir-Rutina-btn').click(function() {

    // Hacemos aparecer la ventana modal donde rellenamos formulario.
    $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').css({
      'display': 'flex',
      'height': 'auto',
      'width': '80%'
    });

    // Creamos las variables donde se describen todos los elementos del formulario
    var titulo1 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Introduce un título general" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo1" />';
    var titulo2 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Objetivo" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo2" />';
    var titulo3 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Ejercicio" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo3" />';
    var titulo4 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Herramienta" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo4" />';
    var titulo5 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Rondas" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo5" />';
    var titulo6 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Repeticiones" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo6" />';
    var titulo7 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Propuesta de peso" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo7" />';
    var titulo8 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Peso usado" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo8" />';

    var cerrarModalBtn = '<input type="button" value="Cancelar" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" id="cerrar-modal-btn" />';
    var guardarModalBtn = '<input type="button" value="Guardar" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" id="Guardar-modal-btn" />';
    var anyadirObjetivo = '<input type="button" value="+" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" id="AnyadirObjetivo-modal-btn" />';
    var anyadirEjercicio = '<input type="button" value="+" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" id="AnyadirEjercicio-modal-btn" />';


    // Insertamos los elementos para que el usuario rellene el formulario
    $('#ModalFila1').append(titulo1);
    $('#ModalFila2').append(titulo2);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo3);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo4);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo5);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo6);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo7);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo8);

    $('#ModalFila1').append(cerrarModalBtn);
    $('#ModalFila1').append(guardarModalBtn);
    $('#ModalFila2').append(anyadirObjetivo);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(anyadirEjercicio);

    // Botón añadir objetivo
    $('#AnyadirObjetivo-modal-btn').click(function() {

      contadorObjetivo = contadorObjetivo + 1;

      $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').append('<div class="ModalFila" id="FilaNuevaObj1' + contadorObjetivo + '"></div>');
      $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').append('<div class="ModalFila" id="FilaNuevaObj2' + contadorObjetivo + '"></div>');

      $('#FilaNuevaObj1' + contadorObjetivo).append(titulo2);
      $('#FilaNuevaObj2' + contadorObjetivo).append(titulo3);
      $('#FilaNuevaObj2' + contadorObjetivo).append(titulo4);
      $('#FilaNuevaObj2' + contadorObjetivo).append(titulo5);
      $('#FilaNuevaObj2' + contadorObjetivo).append(titulo6);
      $('#FilaNuevaObj2' + contadorObjetivo).append(titulo7);
      $('#FilaNuevaObj2' + contadorObjetivo).append(titulo8);
    });

    // Botón añadir ejercicio
    $('#AnyadirEjercicio-modal-btn').click(function() {

      contadorEjercicio = contadorEjercicio + 1;

      $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').append('<div class="ModalFila" id="FilaNuevaEjer' + contadorEjercicio + '"></div>');

      $('#FilaNuevaEjer' + contadorEjercicio).append(titulo3);
      $('#FilaNuevaEjer' + contadorEjercicio).append(titulo4);
      $('#FilaNuevaEjer' + contadorEjercicio).append(titulo5);
      $('#FilaNuevaEjer' + contadorEjercicio).append(titulo6);
      $('#FilaNuevaEjer' + contadorEjercicio).append(titulo7);
      $('#FilaNuevaEjer' + contadorEjercicio).append(titulo8);
    });

    // Botón cerrar. Sale SIN guardar lo escrito.
    $('#cerrar-modal-btn').click(function() {

      // Elimino los elementos creados.
      $('.Inputs-Modal').remove();

      // Hacemos desaparecer la ventana modal
      $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').css('display', 'none');
    });

    // Botón guardar. Guarda y muestra los datos escritos en el formulario. NO VAAAAAAAAAAAA
    $('#Guardar-modal-btn').click(function() {

      // Elimino los elementos creados.
      $('.Inputs-Modal').remove();
      // Hacemos desaparecer la ventana modal
      $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').css('display', 'none');

      var Resultado1 = $("#Titulo1").val();
      var Resultado2 = $("#Titulo2").val();
      var Resultado3 = $("#Titulo3").val();
      var Resultado4 = $("#Titulo4").val();
      var Resultado5 = $("#Titulo5").val();
      var Resultado6 = $("#Titulo6").val();
      var Resultado7 = $("#Titulo7").val();
      var Resultado8 = $("#Titulo8").val();

      $('#Tabla-Rutinas').append(
        '<tr><td colspan="6">' + Resultado1 + '</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><th>' + 'Nombre' + '</th><th>' + 'Herramienta' + '</th><th>' + 'Rondas' + '</th><th>' + 'Repetciones' + '</th><th>' + 'Peso Propuesto' + '</th><th>' + 'Peso Final' + '</th></tr>' +
        '<tr><td colspan="6">' + Resultado2 + '</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td>' + Resultado3 + '</td><td>' + Resultado4 + '</td><td>' + Resultado5 + '</td><td>' + Resultado6 + '</td><td>' + Resultado7 + '</td><td>' + Resultado8 + '</td></tr>'
      );
    });
  });

});
```

```css
#Power-Contenedor h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#Anyadir-Rutina-btn {
  background-color: #21211d;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Modal-Escribir-Rutina {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: #21211d;
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.ModalFila {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.Inputs-Modal {
  padding: 3px;
}

.TextoFormulario {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.BtnFormulario {
  background-color: #fdd063;
  border-color: transparent;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  float: right;
}

#Titulo1 {
  width: 80%;
}

#Titulo2 {
  width: 80%;
}

#Titulo3 {
  width: 40%;
}

#Guardar-modal-btn {
  margin-right: 5px;
}


/**** TABLA ***/

#Tabla-Rutinas {
  height: auto;
  width: 70%;
  /*    background-color: aqua;*/
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Power-Contenedor">

  <h1> Diario de entreno</h1>

  <table id="Tabla-Rutinas"></table>

  <a href="#" id="Anyadir-Rutina-btn"> Añadir entreno </a>

  <div id="Modal-Escribir-Rutina">
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila1"></div>
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila2"></div>
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila3"></div>
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente debes eliminar los elementos creados al final de la ejecución y no antes de capturar e imprimir su valor, ya que al eliminarlos también se elimina su valor.

Creo que ayer te había dicho que crear estructuras tan grandes desde **JS** es una muy mala práctica, además de que tienes un error de estructura en tu tabla, considera cambiarlo, saludos.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var contadorObjetivo = 0; //Contador para añadir objetivo con sus respectivos ejercicios.
  var contadorEjercicio = 0; //Contador para añadir ejercicios.

  // JS para crear rutinas estilo POWER

  $('#Anyadir-Rutina-btn').click(function() {

    // Hacemos aparecer la ventana modal donde rellenamos formulario.
    $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').css({
      'display': 'flex',
      'height': 'auto',
      'width': '80%'
    });

    // Creamos las variables donde se describen todos los elementos del formulario
    var titulo1 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Introduce un título general" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo1" />';
    var titulo2 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Objetivo" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo2" />';
    var titulo3 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Ejercicio" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo3" />';
    var titulo4 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Herramienta" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo4" />';
    var titulo5 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Rondas" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo5" />';
    var titulo6 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Repeticiones" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo6" />';
    var titulo7 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Propuesta de peso" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo7" />';
    var titulo8 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Peso usado" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo8" />';

    var cerrarModalBtn = '<input type="button" value="Cancelar" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" id="cerrar-modal-btn" />';
    var guardarModalBtn = '<input type="button" value="Guardar" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" id="Guardar-modal-btn" />';
    var anyadirObjetivo = '<input type="button" value="+" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" id="AnyadirObjetivo-modal-btn" />';
    var anyadirEjercicio = '<input type="button" value="+" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" id="AnyadirEjercicio-modal-btn" />';


    // Insertamos los elementos para que el usuario rellene el formulario
    $('#ModalFila1').append(titulo1);
    $('#ModalFila2').append(titulo2);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo3);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo4);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo5);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo6);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo7);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo8);

    $('#ModalFila1').append(cerrarModalBtn);
    $('#ModalFila1').append(guardarModalBtn);
    $('#ModalFila2').append(anyadirObjetivo);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(anyadirEjercicio);

    // Botón añadir objetivo
    $('#AnyadirObjetivo-modal-btn').click(function() {

      contadorObjetivo = contadorObjetivo + 1;

      $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').append('<div class="ModalFila" id="FilaNuevaObj1' + contadorObjetivo + '"></div>');
      $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').append('<div class="ModalFila" id="FilaNuevaObj2' + contadorObjetivo + '"></div>');

      $('#FilaNuevaObj1' + contadorObjetivo).append(titulo2);
      $('#FilaNuevaObj2' + contadorObjetivo).append(titulo3);
      $('#FilaNuevaObj2' + contadorObjetivo).append(titulo4);
      $('#FilaNuevaObj2' + contadorObjetivo).append(titulo5);
      $('#FilaNuevaObj2' + contadorObjetivo).append(titulo6);
      $('#FilaNuevaObj2' + contadorObjetivo).append(titulo7);
      $('#FilaNuevaObj2' + contadorObjetivo).append(titulo8);
    });

    // Botón añadir ejercicio
    $('#AnyadirEjercicio-modal-btn').click(function() {

      contadorEjercicio = contadorEjercicio + 1;

      $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').append('<div class="ModalFila" id="FilaNuevaEjer' + contadorEjercicio + '"></div>');

      $('#FilaNuevaEjer' + contadorEjercicio).append(titulo3);
      $('#FilaNuevaEjer' + contadorEjercicio).append(titulo4);
      $('#FilaNuevaEjer' + contadorEjercicio).append(titulo5);
      $('#FilaNuevaEjer' + contadorEjercicio).append(titulo6);
      $('#FilaNuevaEjer' + contadorEjercicio).append(titulo7);
      $('#FilaNuevaEjer' + contadorEjercicio).append(titulo8);
    });

    // Botón cerrar. Sale SIN guardar lo escrito.
    $('#cerrar-modal-btn').click(function() {

      // Elimino los elementos creados.
      $('.Inputs-Modal').remove();

      // Hacemos desaparecer la ventana modal
      $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').css('display', 'none');
    });

    // Botón guardar. Guarda y muestra los datos escritos en el formulario. NO VAAAAAAAAAAAA
    $('#Guardar-modal-btn').click(function() {
      // Hacemos desaparecer la ventana modal
      $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').css('display', 'none');

      var Resultado1 = $("#Titulo1").val();
      var Resultado2 = $("#Titulo2").val();
      var Resultado3 = $("#Titulo3").val();
      var Resultado4 = $("#Titulo4").val();
      var Resultado5 = $("#Titulo5").val();
      var Resultado6 = $("#Titulo6").val();
      var Resultado7 = $("#Titulo7").val();
      var Resultado8 = $("#Titulo8").val();

      $('#Tabla-Rutinas').append(
        '<tr><td colspan="6">' + Resultado1 + '</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><th>' + 'Nombre' + '</th><th>' + 'Herramienta' + '</th><th>' + 'Rondas' + '</th><th>' + 'Repetciones' + '</th><th>' + 'Peso Propuesto' + '</th><th>' + 'Peso Final' + '</th></tr>' +
        '<tr><td colspan="6">' + Resultado2 + '</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td>' + Resultado3 + '</td><td>' + Resultado4 + '</td><td>' + Resultado5 + '</td><td>' + Resultado6 + '</td><td>' + Resultado7 + '</td><td>' + Resultado8 + '</td></tr>'
      );
      
      // Elimino los elementos creados.
      $('.Inputs-Modal').remove();
    });
  });

});
```

```css
#Power-Contenedor h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#Anyadir-Rutina-btn {
  background-color: #21211d;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Modal-Escribir-Rutina {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: #21211d;
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.ModalFila {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.Inputs-Modal {
  padding: 3px;
}

.TextoFormulario {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.BtnFormulario {
  background-color: #fdd063;
  border-color: transparent;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  float: right;
}

#Titulo1 {
  width: 80%;
}

#Titulo2 {
  width: 80%;
}

#Titulo3 {
  width: 40%;
}

#Guardar-modal-btn {
  margin-right: 5px;
}


/**** TABLA ***/

#Tabla-Rutinas {
  height: auto;
  width: 70%;
  /*    background-color: aqua;*/
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Power-Contenedor">

  <h1> Diario de entreno</h1>

  <table id="Tabla-Rutinas"></table>

  <a href="#" id="Anyadir-Rutina-btn"> Añadir entreno </a>

  <div id="Modal-Escribir-Rutina">
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila1"></div>
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila2"></div>
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila3"></div>
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hola! Síayer me lo dijiste, pero es que no se como hacerlo si no es así, puesto que estas tablas las necesito crear de manera dínamica, nunca se que cantidad de filas tendrán ni cuantas tablas habrá. Por eso lo creo mediante JS, si solo fuese hacer aparecer siempre lo mismo lo tendría con `display none` . Aun así gracias, porque a base de pegarme golpes me ensañais muchísimo.

Comment: Por cierto, dices que hay un error de estructura, ¿a que te refieres? Saludos

Comment: @CarlosMilles siendo así lo único dinámico es la tabla no los inputs y esos son los que generas desde JS de manera innecesaria, hasta donde entiendo, ah el error de estructura es que estas agregando los tr y td directamente en la tabla, no estas usando etiqueta tbody que es donde deberían de ir el cual puedes crear en el DOM y seleccionarlos en el JS, saludos

Answer (score 1):

Estás eliminando los inputs antes de capturar su valor. Donde dice:

```
$('#Guardar-modal-btn').click(function() {

      // Elimino los elementos creados.
      $('.Inputs-Modal').remove();
      // Hacemos desaparecer la ventana modal
      $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').css('display', 'none');

      var Resultado1 = $("#Titulo1").val();
      var Resultado2 = $("#Titulo2").val();
      var Resultado3 = $("#Titulo3").val();
      var Resultado4 = $("#Titulo4").val();
      var Resultado5 = $("#Titulo5").val();
      var Resultado6 = $("#Titulo6").val();
      var Resultado7 = $("#Titulo7").val();
      var Resultado8 = $("#Titulo8").val();
   // más código...
});
```

Debieses poner en cambio:

```
$('#Guardar-modal-btn').click(function() {

      var Resultado1 = $("#Titulo1").val();
      var Resultado2 = $("#Titulo2").val();
      var Resultado3 = $("#Titulo3").val();
      var Resultado4 = $("#Titulo4").val();
      var Resultado5 = $("#Titulo5").val();
      var Resultado6 = $("#Titulo6").val();
      var Resultado7 = $("#Titulo7").val();
      var Resultado8 = $("#Titulo8").val();

      // Elimino los elementos creados.
      $('.Inputs-Modal').remove();
      // Hacemos desaparecer la ventana modal
      $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').css('display', 'none');

   // más código...
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var contadorObjetivo = 0; //Contador para añadir objetivo con sus respectivos ejercicios.
  var contadorEjercicio = 0; //Contador para añadir ejercicios.

  // JS para crear rutinas estilo POWER

  $('#Anyadir-Rutina-btn').click(function() {

    // Hacemos aparecer la ventana modal donde rellenamos formulario.
    $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').css({
      'display': 'flex',
      'height': 'auto',
      'width': '80%'
    });

    // Creamos las variables donde se describen todos los elementos del formulario
    var titulo1 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Introduce un título general" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo1" />';
    var titulo2 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Objetivo" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo2" />';
    var titulo3 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Ejercicio" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo3" />';
    var titulo4 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Herramienta" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo4" />';
    var titulo5 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Rondas" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo5" />';
    var titulo6 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Repeticiones" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo6" />';
    var titulo7 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Propuesta de peso" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo7" />';
    var titulo8 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Peso usado" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo8" />';

    var cerrarModalBtn = '<input type="button" value="Cancelar" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" id="cerrar-modal-btn" />';
    var guardarModalBtn = '<input type="button" value="Guardar" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" id="Guardar-modal-btn" />';
    var anyadirObjetivo = '<input type="button" value="+" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" id="AnyadirObjetivo-modal-btn" />';
    var anyadirEjercicio = '<input type="button" value="+" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" id="AnyadirEjercicio-modal-btn" />';


    // Insertamos los elementos para que el usuario rellene el formulario
    $('#ModalFila1').append(titulo1);
    $('#ModalFila2').append(titulo2);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo3);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo4);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo5);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo6);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo7);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo8);

    $('#ModalFila1').append(cerrarModalBtn);
    $('#ModalFila1').append(guardarModalBtn);
    $('#ModalFila2').append(anyadirObjetivo);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(anyadirEjercicio);

    // Botón añadir objetivo
    $('#AnyadirObjetivo-modal-btn').click(function() {

      contadorObjetivo = contadorObjetivo + 1;

      $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').append('<div class="ModalFila" id="FilaNuevaObj1' + contadorObjetivo + '"></div>');
      $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').append('<div class="ModalFila" id="FilaNuevaObj2' + contadorObjetivo + '"></div>');

      $('#FilaNuevaObj1' + contadorObjetivo).append(titulo2);
      $('#FilaNuevaObj2' + contadorObjetivo).append(titulo3);
      $('#FilaNuevaObj2' + contadorObjetivo).append(titulo4);
      $('#FilaNuevaObj2' + contadorObjetivo).append(titulo5);
      $('#FilaNuevaObj2' + contadorObjetivo).append(titulo6);
      $('#FilaNuevaObj2' + contadorObjetivo).append(titulo7);
      $('#FilaNuevaObj2' + contadorObjetivo).append(titulo8);
    });

    // Botón añadir ejercicio
    $('#AnyadirEjercicio-modal-btn').click(function() {

      contadorEjercicio = contadorEjercicio + 1;

      $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').append('<div class="ModalFila" id="FilaNuevaEjer' + contadorEjercicio + '"></div>');

      $('#FilaNuevaEjer' + contadorEjercicio).append(titulo3);
      $('#FilaNuevaEjer' + contadorEjercicio).append(titulo4);
      $('#FilaNuevaEjer' + contadorEjercicio).append(titulo5);
      $('#FilaNuevaEjer' + contadorEjercicio).append(titulo6);
      $('#FilaNuevaEjer' + contadorEjercicio).append(titulo7);
      $('#FilaNuevaEjer' + contadorEjercicio).append(titulo8);
    });

    // Botón cerrar. Sale SIN guardar lo escrito.
    $('#cerrar-modal-btn').click(function() {

      // Elimino los elementos creados.
      $('.Inputs-Modal').remove();

      // Hacemos desaparecer la ventana modal
      $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').css('display', 'none');
    });

    // Botón guardar. Guarda y muestra los datos escritos en el formulario. NO VAAAAAAAAAAAA
    $('#Guardar-modal-btn').click(function() {


      var Resultado1 = $("#Titulo1").val();
      var Resultado2 = $("#Titulo2").val();
      var Resultado3 = $("#Titulo3").val();
      var Resultado4 = $("#Titulo4").val();
      var Resultado5 = $("#Titulo5").val();
      var Resultado6 = $("#Titulo6").val();
      var Resultado7 = $("#Titulo7").val();
      var Resultado8 = $("#Titulo8").val();

      // Elimino los elementos creados.
      $('.Inputs-Modal').remove();
      // Hacemos desaparecer la ventana modal
      $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').css('display', 'none');


      $('#Tabla-Rutinas').append(
        '<tr><td colspan="6">' + Resultado1 + '</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><th>' + 'Nombre' + '</th><th>' + 'Herramienta' + '</th><th>' + 'Rondas' + '</th><th>' + 'Repetciones' + '</th><th>' + 'Peso Propuesto' + '</th><th>' + 'Peso Final' + '</th></tr>' +
        '<tr><td colspan="6">' + Resultado2 + '</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td>' + Resultado3 + '</td><td>' + Resultado4 + '</td><td>' + Resultado5 + '</td><td>' + Resultado6 + '</td><td>' + Resultado7 + '</td><td>' + Resultado8 + '</td></tr>'
      );
    });
  });

});
```

```css
#Power-Contenedor h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#Anyadir-Rutina-btn {
  background-color: #21211d;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Modal-Escribir-Rutina {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: #21211d;
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.ModalFila {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.Inputs-Modal {
  padding: 3px;
}

.TextoFormulario {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.BtnFormulario {
  background-color: #fdd063;
  border-color: transparent;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  float: right;
}

#Titulo1 {
  width: 80%;
}

#Titulo2 {
  width: 80%;
}

#Titulo3 {
  width: 40%;
}

#Guardar-modal-btn {
  margin-right: 5px;
}


/**** TABLA ***/

#Tabla-Rutinas {
  height: auto;
  width: 70%;
  /*    background-color: aqua;*/
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Power-Contenedor">

  <h1> Diario de entreno</h1>

  <table id="Tabla-Rutinas"></table>

  <a href="#" id="Anyadir-Rutina-btn"> Añadir entreno </a>

  <div id="Modal-Escribir-Rutina">
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila1"></div>
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila2"></div>
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila3"></div>
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```